# Why firefox4 is not able to display the li background color?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a background color to a forced inline element..It displays the background color in Ie7 however in firefox4, the color is not displayed..Why is that and how do I sort this out?

the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ybYxq/

```
 <ul id="in">
                <li><h1>sfffffh</h1></li>
                <li><h1>QssssfffffhQ</h1></li>
                <li><h1>ZssssssZ</h1></li>
            </ul>
```

CSS 
    #in li{background:#0CF;display:inline;}
     #in{float:right;}

Comment: my chrome does not show it either.. he?

Comment: Use classes instead and look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/ybYxq/1/

Comment: Can I have any explanation about why my codes are not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vimal try this.

remove the h1 tag from the li and add font styling to li.

the CSS should be.

```
#in li{background-color:#171817;display:inline; color: white; font:12px Tahoma;}
#in{float:right;}
```

the html should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>


                <ul id="in">
                    <li>sfffffh</li>
                    <li>QssssfffffhQ</li>
                    <li>ZssssssZ</li>
                </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

this will work... try any problem just comment me. have a nice day...

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead. You apply to li but you need to apply to h1 too!

[jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/ybYxq/1](http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/ybYxq/1)

You can also use * to apply to everything in li

```
.in li *{background-color:red; display:inline;}
```

Some more examples in this one

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/ybYxq/6/

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it isn't working on Chrome either.

Try :
    #in li{background:#b2b2b2;}
    #in {float: right;}

Or either : 
    #in li{***display:inline-block***; background:#b2b2b2;}
    #in {float: right;}

The second has problems with IE as I remember well.

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate what happens in IE7 in every browser by setting the `h1`s to `display: inline; background:#0CF` instead of setting it on the `li`s:

http://jsfiddle.net/ybYxq/3/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the "blocky" h1 inside the "inline" li is interfering somehow. If you add:

```
#in li h1 { display:inline; }
```

you get the background (at least in Firefox 5).

Answer (score 1):

**Generally the styles from inline elements do not cascade down to block elements.** (IE7 is just a bit buggy)If you change h1 to span(or set h1 as inline) everything will work.